# Wordpress homepage problem

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My wordpress is not setting the front page correctly,

I have several pages, all of them static apart from a news page.  I have set the home page, by going to settings->reading and then setting the static page I want to be front page.

However when I run is_home() it returns false on what I believe to be the homepage. What have I done wrong, or what can I do to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is_home I think only works for posts.

Try is_front_page()